# need help to prove euler's problem on prime numbers in gelfand algebra text.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

if  $P(x) = x^2 + x + 41$ 
compute for $x = 1,2,3..10$ and check if the values are prime.
 I have solved this by trial division.
Might it be that P(1), P(2), P(3)... are all primes?
This one is out of my depth. I vaguely suspect that proof by induction is the way to go but i do not know how. Please guide me through the proof or to relevant readings that will help me.

Comment: They are prime up to and including $x=39$. But not at $40$, nor at $41$. It is not known whether there are infinitely many primes of this shape.

Comment: For reading, you could start [with this.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Prime-GeneratingPolynomial.html)

Comment: You are welcome. Your computations were the sensible approach.